# Azure mobile service pullasync not retrieving data

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin

I've followed all the steps described in [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/mobile-services-xamarin-android-get-started-offline-data/) tutorial (for Xamarin Android) but after I query the toDoTable like this

```
var items = await toDoTable.Where(x => x.Complete == false).ToListAsync();
```

at the end of OnCreate() I can't acces the data stored to the cloud, only the data that I added before on the local database. The

```
await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
```

works just fine because I can see in the cloud the data I've added through my app but the

```
await toDoTable.PullAsync("allTodoItems", toDoTable.CreateQuery());
```

doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the toDoTable.PullAsync command, but the way I inserted data on the table and expected to retrieve it. I was using the mobile-service website and didn't let the table auto-generate data for auto-generated columns

```
{
 "id_user": 1,
 "username": "sample string 2",
 "password": "sample string 3",
 "is_doctor": 4,
 "id": "sample string 5",
 "__version": "QEBA",
 "__createdAt": "2015-06-06T08:21:37.329Z",
 "__updatedAt": "2015-06-06T08:21:37.329Z",
 "__deleted": true
}
```

and was inserting the data above. As soon as I made another insert (the one below) and let these columns be automatically generated I was able to retrieve the data from my table.

```
{
 "id_user": 1,
 "username": "sample string 2",
 "password": "sample string 3",
 "is_doctor": 4,
}
```